# Validating YYYY-MM-DD formatted strings with Zend_Validate_Date in en_US locale

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

I'm validating a user-entered date string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format using `Zend_Validate::is($value,'Date')`.

This call creates this hierarchy:

```
Zend_Validate::is()
Zend_Validate_Date->isValid()
Zend_Date::isDate()
Zend_Locale_Format::getDate()
Zend_Locale_Format::_parseDate()
```

Finally, it fails with this exception:

```
Zend_Locale_Exception: Unable to parse date '2009-09-08' using 'MMM d, y' (M <> y) in /usr/share/php/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 1001
```

I'm using en_US as my application locale. How can I configure Zend_Validate to accept this date format? Is it possible to change the locale format of the date, for example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try that:

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Date('YYYY-MM-DD');
if($validator->isValid($value))
    // yay
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I've never used individual Zend_Validate_X classes before. this is more customizable.

Comment: You should use `'yyyy-MM-dd'` though... YYYY is "ISO Year" (which is subtly different near the beggining of the year) and "DD" day of year not day of month. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.constants.html#zend.date.constants.selfdefinedformats.table

Comment: If you have other validators or a custom validator on the same element, it would be advisable to add this validator as the second (or last)

Answer (score 5):

`zend_validate_date` has a bug , when you specify following `yyyy-MM-dd` format and if a date string `2011-10-11 12312` is passed on for validation, it returns true instead of false !!

Comment: Any updates regarding this bug, It seems I face it also.